# How to Split notepad text into paragraph

Tags: c#

Example of `.txt` file:

```
hello
hello
hello

good
good
good

morning
morning
morning
```

How split this notepad text into 3 variables(1 paragraph in 1 variable)?

Comment: Loop through each line, add each of them into a `StringBuilder` and when you get an empty line just put the `.ToString()` result in a array.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you MUST try by yourself and if have problem with code post a question in SO!

as @dbraillon say in his comment, first use `StreamReader` to open your file something like:

```
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName))
{
        string s = String.Empty;
        while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
               //read every line of your file
        }
}
```

Use a `StringBuilder` to add lines to it:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(s);
```

and in the end of read file use `.ToString()` or use a `foreach` to show whats you want!